# Trying to web-scrape multiple links in r but no idea

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm a total newbie and I'm trying to web scrape from [this](https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/toc/14679868/2018/80/5) site , to get all editions from all the years.

I've been using `rvest` and a selector gadget, but it's useless. Any advice on this, please?

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(xml2)
library(textreadr)

url_base <- "https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/toc/14679868/2018/80/%d"
map_df(1:5, function(i){
       page <- read_html(sprintf(url_base, i))
       data.frame(VolumeID=html_text(html_nodes(page, ".loi-tab-item")),
       IssueID= html_text(html_nodes(page, ".visitable")),
       Heading=html_text(html_nodes(page, ".issue-items-container+ 
       .issue-items-container h2")),
       Author=html_text(html_nodes(page, " .author-style")),
       DOI= html_text(html_nodes(page, ".epub-doi")))

 }) -> royal2018
```

Comment: Do you have the legal permission to scrap this site? If not, do you have access to an API?

Comment: @NelsonGon is webscraping explicitly forbidden in ToS of the site? A simple ctrl+F couldn't find anything of noteworthy. MariaOliveira do you have a specific question about this particular task? Right now, it seems a bit broad.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik It's not very clear. Just wanted to make sure before. Checked and found the ToS not explicit about it.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/robots.txt) could help to know if you can crawl or scrape it.

Comment: Im not sure I have permission, its an assignment at college and I kinda lost. I might have to go to another website.

Comment: what I need is a list of all the editions, issues with articles.. Either from that website or this one http://www.biometria.ufla.br/index.php/BBJ/issue/archive. But Im using a gadget, so I guess its not the best idea. Thanks for the response anyway ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

The second url seems ok, so here some hints to start, I do not know what you'd like to do, maybe scraping some info, so here we go.

First, you can use a selector gadget to find the parts you'd like to scrape, then you can proceed in this way:

```
# your url
url <- "http://www.biometria.ufla.br/index.php/BBJ/issue/archive"

# get all the links in the page
pages_data <- url %>% read_html() %>% 
              html_nodes('.title') %>% 
              html_attr('href')
```

Now, for each page, you can fetch what you need:

```
# titles
titles <- list()                # empty list
for (i in pages_data[1:2]) {    # remove the [1:2] to get all the links
  titles[[i]] <- i %>% 
                 read_html() %>% 
                 html_nodes('.media-heading a') %>%
                 html_text()     
                 Sys.sleep(10)  # important to not pull too much requests in few time  
                           }
```

For the authors:

```
authors <- list()
for (i in pages_data[1:2]) {
  authors[[i]] <- i %>%
                  read_html() %>%
                  html_nodes('.authors') %>%
                  html_text()
                  Sys.sleep(10)
                           }
```

And so on. Now you can combine them as you want, and clean them up.

Comment: I Actually got an error - Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "character

Comment: You're welcome, hope you've found correct my answer as well.